# Matlab GUI: override behaviour of the spacebar key

Tags: matlab, user-interface, keyboard-events

I have built a GUI in matlab using GUIDE, and added keyboard shortcuts to some actions using the WindowKeyPressFcn callback function of my figure. my problem is that I want to use the spacebar as one of the shortcut keys, but it already has a preset usage: it activates the currently selected control (i.e. same as clicking the selected button).

While I can trigger my intended action just fine on the spacebar key through the callback, I found no way to remove this additional unwanted functionality. The result is two actions being performed - the one I programmed and the unintended button press, which creates a mess. The bottom line is that I can't use the spacebar as a shortcut. Is there any way to turn this functionality off or bypass it somehow? Perhaps something that will stop the key-press from reaching the GUI after it is handled by my callback?

I'd prefer a documented Matlab way but if that's not possible, java hacks are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the unwanted behaviour is more OS releated than Matlab related and I know of no wway to remove it, however you can work around it.

One way to do this is to check in your pushbutton callback what was the last key pressed, you do this by adding a KeyPressFcn to your pushbutton.  I have created a simple example below:

```
function spacebarTest
  % create a figure
  hFig = figure ( 'KeyPressFcn', @KeyPress );
  % create a uicontrol
  uicontrol ( 'style', 'pushbutton', 'Callback', @PushButton, 'KeyPressFcn', @KeyPress );
  % store the last key pressed information in the fiure handle
  userData.lastKey = '';
  set ( hFig, 'userData', userData );
end
function KeyPress ( obj, event )
  % obtain the handle for the figure
  hFig = ancestor ( obj, 'figure' );
  % extract the user data 
  userData = get ( hFig, 'userData' );
  % store the last key in the user data
  userData.lastKey = event.Key;
  % update the figure handle user data
  set ( hFig, 'userData', userData );
  disp ( 'spacebar shortcut' );
end
function PushButton ( obj, event )
  % get the figure handle 
  hFig = ancestor ( obj, 'figure' );
  % extract the user data
  userData = get ( hFig, 'userData' );
  % check if spacebar was the last key pressed
  if strcmp ( userData.lastKey, 'space' ); return; end
  disp ( 'running callback - push me' );
end
```

One problem with this is that it still "looks" like your button has been pressed, although the callback has not run.  To resolve this you would need to stop the button ever gaining focus which you would need to replace your uicontrol button with a JButton (java) and use the [FocusGainedCallback](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks)